# cpp gdb valgrind - memory usage statistic while app is running and valgrind unhandled syscall

Tags: c++, memory, gdb, valgrind

1) I want to get information about memory usage while my program is running (by request). My program create `session-objects` on the fly and I want to get information about memory usage of all there objects. Is it possible? Seems this can be done by `Valgrind`. How to use it? How to run it? (commands)

2) My program is background multithread daemon (it also use Local Unix Sockets). 
I can not run my program under valdrind `valdrind ./daemon start`. I got following tons of messages:

```
--19454-- it at http://valgrind.org/support/bug_reports.html.
caught signal 5068246
--19454-- WARNING: unhandled syscall: 429
--19454-- You may be able to write your own handler.
--19454-- Read the file README_MISSING_SYSCALL_OR_IOCTL.
--19454-- Nevertheless we consider this a bug.  Please report
--19454-- it at http://valgrind.org/support/bug_reports.html.
caught signal 5068246
```

What is the problem and how to fix it?

3) maybe there is other ways to get information about objects and memory usage by them? Maybe `gdb` or other tools?

ps. sorry for my english, please.

Comment: What platform are you on? Is it Linux or something else? Do you use glibc or something else? What processor?

Comment: @EmployedRussian I am testing it on FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE under VM VirtualBox. Emulated 2-core processor. Compiled with GCC (guess it using glibc)

Comment: Did you report this as a bug as mentioned in the output? "Nevertheless we consider this a bug.  Please report..."

Comment: @Brady no, I does not. I start from creating thread...

Comment: mean thread at stackoverflow :)))))

Comment: did you read http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.readme-missing.html