# gdb - get exactly unexpected error from core file

Tags: c++, gdb

What exactly I need to do to get the unexpected error code or something similar to it form the core file with GDB or some other tool, to get the idea why my daemon died at operator `new`?

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x48775bd7 in thr_kill () from /lib/libc.so.7
#1  0x48726f46 in pthread_kill () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#2  0x487245da in raise () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#3  0x4880abba in abort () from /lib/libc.so.7
#4  0x4866e65f in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler ()
   from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x486729aa in std::set_unexpected () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x486729f2 in std::terminate () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x486728ea in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x486c77ac in operator new () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x0806ad4c in XXX::process_in (this=0x4b110d40,
    map_settings_to_save=@0x7f7fcc98, str_answer=@0x7f7fcf84)
    at Click.cpp:2940
```

Comment: Show us some code where your program dies

Comment: Today daimon died at this line of code `ptr_it_thumb = new std::list<MyContainer>::iterator();`. Daimon can work up to 2-30 days online. And die one day. How to get `what exactly new() operator throw()`...

Comment: Either your heap is corrupt or you're just plain out of memory for the process. I'm not going to ask why you're dynamically constructing an iterator, but the latter problem, if attributed to a memory leak, is identifiable via tools like Valgrind with little effort.

Comment: @WhozCraig I store on the session iterators to obj. in the map to get quick access to them without searching at the next time. Of course time to time I clean my sessions with operator `delete`. But the question about core file and gdb...

Comment: @abrahab my comment doesn't change that. You could always wrap your `new` request in an exception handler and determine for yourself `what()` the cause is, but the actual dump is due to an unhanded exception. *Why* `operator new` threw the exception (corruption or o-o-m) makes little difference, as both are productions of an ill-formed program. If you question is simply "can you tell *why the exception was thrown*, given only a core-file after-the-fac", no you can't. The stack is already unwound to the termination handler. A gdb catchpoint *may* assist a running process, but not a core.

Comment: @WhozCraig seems the good idea to submit this comment as the answer. But what I must do with catched exception of new? So, the easises way, of course, is `terminate()` but how to store the exception? To the log file, but if program `out of memory` or something similar -- I'm note sure that it can execute some code to store the error on the file or database... And to make not "ill-formed" program you suggest to catch() all exceptions?

Comment: Catching the unexpected exception isn't a step to well-formed. By ill-formed I mean your program is unintentionally consuming memory to the point of exhaustion (often attributed to a leak), intentionally consuming said-same (bad algorithm), or you're corrupting the heap (a double-delete, overwrite, etc). Were I trying to track this down I would run it under Valgrind as a non-service (regular prog) for a few days, then issue a clean-shutdown signal (whichever you use), and check the valgrind report. If its a leak or an overwrite, valgrind will probably find it.

Comment: And I'm leaving this without an answer only because I don't believe you can do what you want (use gdb to backtrace the exception), but I'm not fluent in gdb as others may be, and someone may well have a way around this for you we've not thought of. I would find such an answer most-intriguing and have thus up-ticked your question. Best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for your good answers. Unfortunately, I can not run valgrind on this FreeBSD system ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861384/cpp-gdb-valgrind-memory-usage-statistic-while-app-is-running-and-valgrind-unha ). Currently, app designed to keep all sessions on the memory and maybe there is a problem. Hard to control over 50000+ objects by it's size on the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Go to line 2940 of Click.cpp; you should find that someone is instantiating a new object. There was some error in the constructor.

From the looks of it, the heap in your application is trashed.

If the program used to work, and you changed something before this, potentially something that could have damaged the heap, check that carefully.